# Specify Client Secret After Stripe has been Instantiated

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

Stripe provides [example in docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react) for using `PaymentElement` where they create the `<Elements>` component at the root of the app and wrap it around the entire website. This works well with being able to access the stripe object from anywhere within the app using the `useStripe` and `useElements` hooks.

However, when they create elements at the root, they also specify the `options` parameter which contains a `clientPromise`. `clientPromise` can only be obtained once the item being purchased is known. Hence, I need to generate the `clientPromise` in a subcomponent that deals with checkout.

**Stripe Docs Code**

```
const stripePromise = loadStripe('fake_test_key');

function App() {
  const options = {
    // passing the client secret obtained from the server
    clientSecret: fetchClientSecretFromServer(), 
  };

  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
      <CheckoutForm />
    </Elements>
  );
};
```

Is there a way to manually set clientPromise, or overwrite stripe options in a component that is a child of `<Elements>` instead of having to generate it at the point where the ` component is rendered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately I think the only way to handle this is to delay the loading of `Elements` until you know the details of the purchase.

All of [react-stripe-js](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js) is just a React style wrapper around classes and methods provided by [stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/js).  If you examine how [Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) and [Setup Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) docs make use of the [stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/js) elements, they are always instantiated after the creation of the Intent object and the sending of the `clientSecret` to the front-end.